# Wordpress site returning 404 error when requesting content from subfolders

Tags: php, apache, wampserver

I'm using WAMPSERVER to run a wordpress site that has to be acessible by the users in my network, like a environment for testing together.

Localhost works fine, but at first i couldn't access the aplication from other computers in the network. I created a rule to open the port 80, created an Alias in the Apache configuration, and it worked but the theme and any images inside subfolders wouldn't load and the console was returning lots of 404 responses.

I want to map the subfolders and its files that are under the 'base dir' of the site. I tried tons of options in the Apache conf. file but i couldn't make it.

Attached a printscreen of the responses, the apache conf file and the windows hosts file

Httpd.conf :

```
NameVirtualHost *:80


<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"
ServerName localhost
ErrorLog "logs/localhost-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/localhost-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@animamidia
DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\website"
ServerName www.animamidia
ErrorLog "logs/animamidia-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/animamidia-access.log" common

<Directory "C:\wamp\www\website\*">
Options FollowSymLinks Includes
    AllowOverride All
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all

</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Windows hosts file:

127.0.0.1       www.animamidia

[The site with it's theme broken because the requisition returned a 404](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6XXf.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i found the problem.

Even though i couldn't enter the wordpress-admin i decided to check the 'wp-config.php' file just in case something is wrong or missing.

And what i did find is that the 'Home-URL' and the 'WP-URL' were set at 'localhost/website' which means that all the requisitions would point at this location as a base directory.

All i had to do was to use the 'define' comand and set the site's URL to the machine's IP and now the environment is all set up for the guys over here to develop and test their stuff.